# Not able to run python script from Gradle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gradle, build.gradle

I have tried following code but not sure what is the issue

```
task runPython(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'C:\\Users\\adityaj\\git\\Learn\\TestProject'
    commandLine 'python', 'main.py'
}
```

[image: Project Hierarchy]

Also attached project hierarchy

Below is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'com.gradle.plugin-publish' version '0.9.10'
    id 'eclipse'
}
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
//apply plugin: 'py-build'

repositories { 
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'pypi:Werkzeug:0.7'
  testCompile 'pypi:Jinja2:2.4'
  testCompile 'pypi:itsdangerous:0.21'
  testCompile 'pypi:click:2.0'
}

task runPython(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'C:\\Users\\adityaj\\git\\Learn\\TestProject'
    commandLine 'python', 'main.py'
}
test {
    testLogging {
        events 'skipped', 'failed', 'standard_error'
        exceptionFormat 'full'
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message that you had?

Comment: try setting it to root directory likewise: 
  
    workingDir './TestProject'